# Using jsonPath looking for a string

Tags: jsonpath, krl

I'm trying to use jsonPath and the pick function to determine if a rule needs to run or not based on the current domain. A simplified version of what I'm doing is here:

```
    global 
{
    dataset shopscotchMerchants <- "https://s3.amazonaws.com/app-files/dev/merchantJson.json" cachable for 2 seconds
}

rule checkdataset is active
{
    select when pageview ".*" setting ()
    pre
    {
        merchantData = shopscotchMerchants.pick("$.merchants[?(@.merchant=='Telefora')]");
    }
    emit 
    <|
        console.log(merchantData);
    |>
}
```

The console output I expect is the telefora object, instead I get all three objects from the json file.

If instead of merchant=='Telefora' I use merchantID==16 then it works great. I thought jsonPath could do matches to strings as well. Although the example above isn't searching against the merchantDomain part of the json, I'm experiencing the same problem with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that, as stated in [the documentation](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Simple_Predicates), the string equality operators are `eq`, `neq`, and `like`. `==` is only for numbers. In your case, you want to test if one string is equal to another string, which is the job of the `eq` string equality operator.

Simply swap `==` for `eq` in you JSONpath filter expression and you will be good to go:

```
    global 
{
    dataset shopscotchMerchants <- "https://s3.amazonaws.com/app-files/dev/merchantJson.json" cachable for 2 seconds
}

rule checkdataset is active
{
    select when pageview ".*" setting ()
    pre
    {
        merchantData = shopscotchMerchants.pick("$.merchants[?(@.merchant eq 'Telefora')]"); // replace == with eq
    }
    emit 
    <|
        console.log(merchantData);
    |>
}
```

I put this to the test in my own test ruleset, the source for which is below:

```
ruleset a369x175 {
  meta {
    name "test-json-filtering"
    description <<

    >>
    author "AKO"
    logging on
  }

  dispatch {
      domain "exampley.com"
  }

  global {
    dataset merchant_dataset <- "https://s3.amazonaws.com/app-files/dev/merchantJson.json" cachable for 2 seconds
  }

  rule filter_some_delicous_json {
    select when pageview "exampley.com"
    pre {
        merchant_data = merchant_dataset.pick("$.merchants[?(@.merchant eq 'Telefora')]");
    }
    {
        emit <|
            try { console.log(merchant_data); } catch(e) { }
        |>;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between `eq` and `==`. That one has been confusing to 462 students (and other newcomers).

Comment: Nice! I was getting confused because I was looking at the actual jsonPath docs and seeing if I could get those to work. Thanks Alex!

Comment: How would the like operator look in this situation? I'm having trouble getting the regular expression to work.