# How to filter by string in JSONPath?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a JSON response from the Facebook API that looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
     {
       "name": "Barack Obama", 
       "category": "Politician", 
       "id": "6815841748"
     }, 
     {
       "name": "Barack Obama's Dead Fly", 
       "category": "Public figure", 
       "id": "92943557739"
     }]
 }
```

I want to apply JSONPath to it to only return results with a category of "Politician". From what I've read, it appears that I need to do:

```
$.data[?(@.category=='Politician')]
```

but according to the [testing tool](http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) I found, this doesn't work. I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560455/using-jsonpath-looking-for-a-string) which suggests that I should use "eq" instead of "==", but that doesn't work either. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: I believe this is because what's in the round brackets is actually dependent on the scripting engine you are using to evaluate. If you were using JavaScript I would expect it to work, however not all JsonPath implementations may use the same or any scripting language. Sorry I'm very late to answer this.

Comment: This is the site I use: https://www.javainuse.com/jsonpath  Having conditions inside of conditions works on this site but not on others.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your query looks fine, and your data and query work for me using [this JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) parser. Also see the example queries on that page for more predicate examples.

The testing tool that you're using seems faulty. Even the examples from the [JsonPath site](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) are returning incorrect results:

e.g., given:

```
{
    "store":
    {
        "book":
        [ 
            { "category": "reference",
              "author": "Nigel Rees",
              "title": "Sayings of the Century",
              "price": 8.95
            },
            { "category": "fiction",
              "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
              "title": "Sword of Honour",
              "price": 12.99
            },
            { "category": "fiction",
              "author": "Herman Melville",
              "title": "Moby Dick",
              "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
              "price": 8.99
            },
            { "category": "fiction",
              "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
              "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
              "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
              "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle":
        {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    }
}
```

And the expression: `$.store.book[?(@.length-1)].title`, the tool returns a list of *all* titles.

Comment: `$.store.book[*].title` will provide the same result.

Answer (score 14):

I didn't find find the correct jsonpath filter syntax to extract a value from a name-value pair in json.

Here's the syntax and an abbreviated sample twitter document below.

[This site](http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) was useful for testing:

The jsonpath filter expression:

```
.events[0].attributes[?(@.name=='screen_name')].value
```

Test document:

```
{
  "title" : "test twitter",
  "priority" : 5,
  "events" : [ {
    "eventId" : "150d3939-1bc4-4bcb-8f88-6153053a2c3e",
    "eventDate" : "2015-03-27T09:07:48-0500",
    "publisher" : "twitter",
    "type" : "tweet",
    "attributes" : [ {
      "name" : "filter_level",
      "value" : "low"
    }, {
      "name" : "screen_name",
      "value" : "_ziadin"
    }, {
      "name" : "followers_count",
      "value" : "406"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Drop the quotes:

```
List<Object> bugs = JsonPath.read(githubIssues, "$..labels[?(@.name==bug)]");
```

See also this [Json Path Example page](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/parse-json-elements-with-jsonpath/)

Answer (score 3):

The browser testing tools while convenient can be a bit deceiving. Consider:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Encounter",
  "id": "EMR56788",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
    "div": "Patient admitted with chest pains</div>"
  },
  "status": "in-progress",
  "class": "inpatient",
  "patient": {
    "reference": "Patient/P12345",
    "display": "Roy Batty"
  }
}
```

Most tools returned this as false:

```
$[?(@.class==inpatient)]
```

But when I executed against

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It returned true. I recommend writing a simple unit test to verify rather than rely on the browser testing tools.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, if you notice in your JSON the `status` key is at different hierarchy level. How can I search for all `status` attribute here dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

''Alastair, you can use this lib and tool; DefiantJS. It enables XPath queries on JSON structures and you can test and validate this XPath:

```
//data[category="Politician"]
```

DefiantJS extends the global object with the method "search", which in turn returns an array with the matches. In Javascript, it'll look like this:

```
var person = JSON.search(json_data, "//people[category='Politician']");
console.log( person[0].name );
// Barack Obama
```