# Json Path querying without an array

Tags: c#, json, jsonpath, json-query

In the below JSON I am trying to find a condition.Where I want the result only if OrderNumber is not empty or null.

Conditions I have tried. But havent worked for me are:

```
> $..Item[?(@.OrderNumber)]
> $..Item[?(@.CurrentOrder.OrderNumber)]
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
I am testing my queries here https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

```
{
        "Response": {
            "ID": "123456",
             "Items": {
                "Item": [
                    {                       
                        "CurrentOrder": {
                            "OrderNumber": "123",
                            "Status": ""
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using Newtonsoft's `JToken.SelectTokens()` then this might not be implemented.  See [JSONPath scripts not executing correctly for objects #1256](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256) and [Json.NET JSONPath query not returning expected results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298348/3744182).

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] showing what API you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$..Item[?(@.CurrentOrder.OrderNumber)]` is the correct JSONPath for your case.

The tool you used is known to not working correctly. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585968/how-to-filter-by-string-in-jsonpath).

I have test above query with [JSONPath Online Evaluator](http://jsonpath.com) and for JSON

```
{
    "Response": {
        "ID": "123456",
        "Items": {
            "Item": [
                {
                    "CurrentOrder": {
                        "OrderNumber": "123",
                        "Status": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "CurrentOrder": {
                        "OrderNumber": "456",
                        "Status": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "CurrentOrder": {
                        "Status": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

it gives correct result:

```
[
  {
    "CurrentOrder": {
      "OrderNumber": "123",
      "Status": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "CurrentOrder": {
      "OrderNumber": "456",
      "Status": ""
    }
  }
]
```