# Load nested JSON with incremental key/timestamp into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a JSON dataset (see below a part of it). I want to use it in a flattened Pandas DataFrame to have access to all columns, in particular "A" and "B "with some data as columns for further processing.

```
import pandas as pd

datajson= {
    "10001": {
      "extra": {"user": "Tom"},
      "data":{"A":5, "B":10}
    },
    "10002":{
      "extra": {"user": "Ben"},
      "data":{"A":7, "B":20}
    },
    "10003":{
      "extra": {"user": "Ben"},
      "data":{"A":6, "B":15}
    }
  }
df = pd.read_json(datajson, orient='index')
# same with DataFrame.from_dict
# df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datajson, orient='index')
```

which results in [Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ej6c.jpg).

I am assuming there is a simple way without looping/appending and making a complicated and slow decoder but rather using for example Panda's json_normalize().

Comment: How about using [JSONPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587220/1176573)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do that without looping through the json. You can do that relatively efficiently though if you make use of a list comprehension:

```
def parse_inner_dictionary(data):
    return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i, index=[0]) for i in data.values()], axis=1)


df = pd.concat([parse_inner_dictionary(v) for v in datajson.values()])
df.index = datajson.keys()
print(df)

      user  A   B
10001  Tom  5  10
10002  Ben  7  20
10003  Ben  6  15
```